# Adding multiple videos to youtube-playlist via API (Python)

Tags: python, loops, youtube, youtube-api, playlist

I'm having troubles adding multiple videos to an already existing playlist on YouTube.

Currently, I can add multiple videos by repeating a fragment of code (the bit from `request =` to `print(f"\n{response}")`) with different video IDs over and over again in my script ; but, I' like to find a smarter and better way to do that.

I already tried to read other posts regarding this problem, but unfortunately, they did not work for me.

Also, I checked the Google YouTube API documentation but I could not find a solution for my problem over there.

Since this is my first post, please let me know if I need to add more information for the community to solve the problem.

This is the code I'm currently working with :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Sample Python code for youtube.playlistItems.insert
# See instructions for running these code samples locally:
# https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#python

import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "XXXX.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.playlistItems().insert(
        part="snippet",
        body={
          "snippet": {
            "playlistId": "playlist-xy", #an actual playlistid
            "position": 0,
            "resourceId": {
              "kind": "youtube#video",
              "videoId": "videoid-xy" #an actual videoid
            }
          }
        }
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(f"\n{response}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Batch Processing option](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/batch.md) provided by the API.

Instead of creating individual requests, you create a batch and then add all the requests to it and then execute. Assuming you store all your video ids in a list `videoIds`:

```
youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)
batch = youtube.new_batch_http_request()
for videoId in videoIds:
    batch.add(youtube.playlistItems().insert(
        part="snippet",
        body={
          "snippet": {
            "playlistId": "playlist-xy", #an actual playlistid
            "position": 0,
            "resourceId": {
              "kind": "youtube#video",
              "videoId": videoId
            }
          }
        }
      )
    )
responses = batch.execute()
```

You can also set up a *callback function* which gets called for the response to each batch item. Info on that is provided on the page linked above.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so fast! Unfortunately I do not have the skill set (yet) to implement the suggestion you made. But I found a workaround that will do the job for now. When I learned more about YT-APIs, Python I will give it another try!

Comment: What do you mean by _"I do not have the skill set (yet) to implement the suggestion you made"_ ? Do you have a list of `videoIds` somewhere? Also, if you have another solution or workaround, feel free to post that as an additional answer to your question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm so new to this and English is not my native tongue. I do not even know where to copy and paste this in my code (Or if I'm even able to copy and paste this). And where the list of video ids goes that I eventually want to loop (I guess right before the section you posted). It's a bit embarrassing and I do not want to bother anyone asking questions I should figure out myself. My solution is to copy the part from the "request" to "print" section into Excel, add the individual videoID via a function and then copy and paste this back into my IDE and run it.

Comment: The code in my answer would go after the line `credentials = flow.run_console()` in your code, and replaces the parts below it. And oh god pls don't try to generate the code by creating a formula or function in Excel to create that loop for each videoID. The easiest thing would be: put `videoIDs = []` in main() or before the loop and paste in the IDs, add commas, quotes, etc. For each step that you're trying to do, search on StackOverflow to find how you could. No one can do _everything_ from the very start. It's a learning curve :-)